# Adding more condition while joining or in where which is better?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
    SELECT C.* 
      FROM Content C
INNER JOIN ContentPack CP ON C.ContentPackId = CP.ContentPackId 
                         AND CP.DomainId = @DomainId
```

...and:

```
    SELECT C.* 
      FROM Content C
INNER JOIN ContentPack CP ON C.ContentPackId = CP.ContentPackId
     WHERE CP.DomainId = @DomainId
```

Is there any performance difference between this 2 queries?

Comment: Since the condition `CP.DomainId = @DomainId` really doesn't have anything to do with the JOIN (it doesn't establish a link between the two tables), I would recommend query #2. I would try to put only conditions that link the two tables of a JOIN into the JOIN condition - everything else belongs in the general WHERE clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because both queries use an INNER JOIN, there is no difference -- they're equivalent.
That wouldn't be the case if dealing with an OUTER JOIN -- criteria in the `ON` clause is applied *before* the join; criteria in the `WHERE` is applied *after the join*.

But your query would likely run better as:

```
SELECT c.* 
  FROM CONTENT c
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM CONTENTPACK cp
                WHERE cp.contentpackid = c.contentpackid
                  AND cp.domainid = @DomainId)
```

Using a JOIN risks duplicates if there's more than one `CONTENTPACK` record related to a `CONTENT` record.  And it's pointless to JOIN if your query is not using columns from the table being JOINed to...  JOINs are not always the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

There's no performance difference but I would prefer the inner join because I think it makes very clear what is it that you are trying to join on both tables.